# Generating an HTML page using a bash script, but image tags are broken

Tags: html, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo
echo "<h1>You Rolled 9 dice</h1>"
dice=( /images/die1.png /images/die2.png /images/die3.png /images/die4.png /images/die5.png  /images/die6.png)
index=$RANDOM
let "index = index % 6"
href="${dice[$index]}"
echo "<a href=$href><img src=$href></a>"
```

This is what I have so far. I want the page to stay text/html because I'm going to be writing more on it. It keeps telling me that the requested URL /images/die5.png was not found on this server.

Comment: "Using bash in my browser"? I'm not sure that I understand; could you please clarify what you mean by this? Do you mean that you run a `.sh` file to generate a HTML file?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. This is my first time, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to remove the leading `/` character from your image file names:

```
#!/bin/bash

dice=(images/die1.png images/die2.png images/die3.png images/die4.png images/die5.png images/die6.png)
index=$RANDOM
let "index = index % 6"
href="${dice[$index]}"

echo '<!DOCTYPE html>'
echo '<html>'
echo '  <head>'
echo '    <meta charset="utf-8">'
echo '    <title>Example</title>'
echo '  </head>'
echo '  <body>'
echo '    <h1>You Rolled 9 dice</h1>'
echo "    <a href='$href'><img src='$href' alt='image'></a>"
echo '  </body>'
echo '</html>'
```

After running the script like so:

```
thomas@yozu-thomas:~/Programming/bashbrowser$ ./makehtm.sh > out.htm
```

The output I get is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>You Rolled 9 dice</h1>
    <a href='images/die3.png'><img src='images/die3.png' alt='image'></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

...which looks like this:

[image]

Note: I'm assuming that the file structure is something like this:

- `makehtm.sh`
- `out.htm`
- `images/`

  - `die1.png`
  - `die2.png`
  - `die3.png`
  - `die4.png`
  - `die5.png`
  - `die6.png`

Additionally, you don't need to `echo "Content-type: text/html"` within the HTML page itself; this is an [HTTP header field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), and will be handled by the web server that hosts the HTML file.